# Asking for a supply chain shock index and the like

Tags: macroeconomics

I am looking for an index about the supply chain shock. My senior consultant suggest that it relates to something called "international shipment freight cost".

I am wondering **if there is any index relating to "international shipment freight cost"** regionally or globally for each country.

Or something like **freight cost, index for international shipping costs** as **supply chain shocks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Bloomberg: Baltic Dry Index(BDI), Shanghai Containerized Freight Index(SCFI) etc

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Freightos data](https://fbx.freightos.com/): Global Container Freight Index. This index is often used as a proxy of supply chain disruptions.

Comment: it seems that it is the one, because my senior friend mentioned the Baltic index something quite a bit, lemme check it. But thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the article "Supply chain bottlenecks in the euro area and the United States: where do we stand?" in the ECB's 02/2022 Economic Bulletin at [https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/economic-bulletin/focus/2022/html/ecb.ebbox202202_01~272e32f7f4.en.html](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/economic-bulletin/focus/2022/html/ecb.ebbox202202_01%7E272e32f7f4.en.html)

It provides various potential indicators for various sectors:
[image]